# Why macro F1 measure can't be calculated from macro precision and recall?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I'm interested in calculating macro f1-score by macro precision and recall manually. But the results aren't equal. What is the difference in the final formula between f1 and f1_new in code?

```python
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

y_true = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0 , 1, 1, 0]
y_pred = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1 , 1, 0, 0]

p = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
r = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
f1_new = (2 * p * r) / (p + r) # 0.6291390728476821

f1 = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro') #  0.6190476190476191

print(f1_new == f1) 
# False
```

Comment: Taking averages in different orders and aggregating leads to different results. This is about a mathematical relationship; it belongs on [stats.SE], not here.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I vote to close ML theory/methodoogy questions as off-topic all the time, but this doesn't seem to be the case here. This seems like an implementation issue (even if it is about sklearn internals) with a fully reproducible minimal example, so I do think it belongs here indeed.

Answer (score 4):

The `f1_score` is calculated in scikit-learn as follows:

```python
all_positives = 4
all_negatives = 4
true_positives = 2
true_negatives = 3

true_positive_rate = true_positives/all_positives = 2/4
true_negative_rate = true_negatives/all_negatives = 3/4

pred_positives = 3
pred_negatives = 5

positive_predicted_value = true_positives/pred_positives = 2/3
negative_predicted_value = true_negatives/pred_negatives = 3/5

f1_score_pos = 2 * true_positive_rate * positive_predicted_value / (true_positive_rate + positive_predicted_value)
             = 2 * 2/4 * 2/3 / (2/4 + 2/3)

f1_score_neg = 2 * true_negative_rate * negative_predicted_value / (true_negative_rate + negative_predicted_value)
             = 2 * 3/4 * 3/5 / (3/4 + 3/5)

f1 = average(f1_score_pos, f1_score_neg)
   = 2/4 * 2/3 / (2/4 + 2/3) + 3/4 * 3/5 / (3/4 + 3/5)
   = 0.6190476190476191
```

This matches the definition given in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) for the `'macro'` parameter of skicit-learn's `f1_score`: *Calculate metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean*. This definition also applies to `precision_score` and `recall_score`.

Your manual calculation of the F1-score is as follows:

```python
precision = average(positive_predicted_value, negative_predicted_value)
          = average(2/3, 3/5)
          = 19/30

recall = average(true_positive_rate, true_negative_rate)
       = average(2/4, 3/4)
       = 5/8

f1_new = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall)
       = 2 * 19/30 * 5/8 / (19/30 + 5/8)
       = 0.6291390728476821
```

In fact, the general formula `F1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)` as presented in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) is only valid for `average='binary'` and `average='micro'`, but not for `average='macro'` and `average='weighted'`. In that sense, as it is currently presented in scikit-learn, the formula is misleading as it suggests that it holds irrespective of the chosen parameters, which is not the case.

Comment: Cool. Maybe we should open an issue pointing this out and asking for a clarification to be added in the docs.